# Is one major and one minor scale instrument enough to play any melody?

Tags: scales, melody, harmonica

If I buy a diatonic harmonica, I can play one octave of a major scale and its relative minor properly. Is that enough to play any melody by transcribing to the key of my harmonica?

Comment: I would say no, given more complicated music often has notes outside the typical scale

Answer (score 3):

One thing to point out, you mentioned being able to play one octave of a major or minor scale. One octave is not enough range for many songs because a song may start below or go above the one octave that is available to you. For example, Happy Birthday. If you have only one octave from tonic to tonic you cannot play it because it starts on the 5th below the tonic.

Fortunately a typical diatonic harmonica spans 3 octaves so you won’t have that problem because of the range it offers. Unfortunately it will not allow you to play “any” melody because it only has 7 notes out of the 12 chromatic notes and many melodies use notes that are outside the 7 note diatonic scale. However there are MANY songs that are written with only the diatonic scale so you will be able to have plenty of songs to choose from. Another limitation which you mentioned, is for the most part you will only be able to play melodies in the key the harmonica is constructed in. However, if a melody is very simple (3 to 5 notes) you might be able to play something in more than one key, say on a C harmonica you might be able to play a song in F or G too.

A chromatic harmonica has a lever that transposes the instrument up a semitone allowing you to access all 12 notes of the chromatic scale. This allows you to play pretty much any melody in any key.

An interesting anecdote, years ago a friend (a very good jazz musician) showed me he could play chromatic melodies on a diatonic harmonica by bending the notes to get the chromatic notes in between the diatonic ones and proceeded to play a very complex chromatic melody on it. This however took a lot of skill and practice and I haven’t personally heard many people that can do it well.

Comment: And here I was hoping to play some Schoenberg on my harmonica.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you can but you have to be REALLY good!

Comment: Yeah. I also know such a wizard, he actually can play Schönberg or Stravinsky on diatonic harmonica. Unfortunately the audience never appreciates this kind of thing... it doesn't help that harmonica players are typically typecast into their Blues stereotype.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Amazing... haven’t heard anyone play classical on one but the guy I mentioned was able to play Charlie Parker type bebop lines at a pretty brisk tempo ala Toots.

Comment: There is a lot here that sounds strange for a harmonica player (or to this one at least). The fifth below the tonic is not absent in the first octave, but the 6th is. You can play Happy Birthday in the top octave without bends though. Most blues players _don't_ play in the key it's made for, but mostly in the dominant key. Though most players can't play ALL chromatic notes, most can play quite a few. The sentence "a typical diatonic harmonica spans 3 octaves and one note" assumes a solid overdraw on hole 10(crazy hard for +99%), but in the rest of your text you assume no bending at all. etc...

Comment: @EdvinW my comments about playing “Happy Birthday” are based on the fact that most melodies are more than 1 octave and the OP said “ I can play one octave of a major scale and its relative minor properly”. I was making the point that playing more than 1 octave on a harmonica is possible. As for my 3 octaves and one note, I was referring to the final high octave note, which is the first note of the next octave. As for playing in the dominant key, blues players do that but someone that wants to play regular diatonic melodies won’t be playing a harmonica in the dominant key..

Comment: @EdvinW BTW I can see how “3 octaves and one note” can be a little misleading so I changed it to 3 octaves.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr: The diatonic harmonica can be a fully chromatic instrument, spanning 3 octaves, with a very wide expressive range and the possibility to bend many of the notes. While other wind instruments allows for some bending as well, it's pretty unique in combing this with being able to play chords.**

(I will assume you buy a C harmonica, simply because the notes are easier to write about in that key. If you want to play a lot in the top octave a lower key might be better.)

(Edit: I will also assume you don't buy the cheapest harmonica you can find. A $5 toy will not offer much room for development, but starting around $40 most instruments are decent.)

If you buy a standard diatonic blues harmonica you can **immediately** play three chords: Two major and one minor. Also, one of the major chords spans the whole three octave range, so you can play it in many different ways. This can already be useful.

**With not-so-much practice**, you would learn to play one note at a time. There will be some notes missing, but you'll be able to play these notes:

```
Bottom Octave: C D E   G   B(C)
Middle Octave: C D E F G A B(C)
Top    Octave: C D E F G A   C
```

(Edit: The (C)'s are the same as the C's on the next line, they are doubled as they could be said to be part of either octave.)

Several notes missing, but a lot more than a single octave! You can play a lot of major and minor stuff already with this. The easiest way to play some simple minor songs is to play in Dm. Some notes are missing, but a lot of stuff will be available. (I was myself content with this for several years and learned to play pretty advanced music within this framework.)

**This is just the beginning though.** Some people would assume you stop here, and say something like "playing more notes on harmonica is impossible, unless you learn advanced techniques". My answer to this is that a guitar is also pretty limited, unless you learn barre chords and other quite "advanced" techniques. Most instruments have some simple stuff you can learn quickly, but they require work before you can "play anything". Harmonicas are not different.

If you do **put in a little work**, you can learn to bend notes, which not only vastly increases the number of available notes, but also lets you do the soulful glides between notes that harmonicas are famous for.

Of course there's a lot of other techniques one can learn to get other chords, cool sounds etc. If yo cut the fancy stuff though, and talk in terms of playing melodies, this is basically the level most diatonic harmonica players are at. You do miss a few notes, but it's easier to list the missing ones than to list those you have:

```
Bottom Octave: Eb 
Middle Octave: Eb F# Bb 
Upper  Octave: C# G#
```

Reaching this level is a perfectly reasonable goal for a beginner to achieve!

You don't have to stop here though.

If you **show some dedication**, you can learn to play the missing notes as well. 30 years ago this was pretty uncommon, but with the internet and online tutorials in every person's pocket many people learn to do it.

I conclude with some links to videos that hint at the range of what modern players can do. (I don't know what genres you are interested in, but if you tell me I could expand the list to cover that)

- Mike Stevens, bluegrass:
- Will Wilde, alternative tuning, blues-rock :
- Joel Andersson Irish(with a lot of chords!):

(I don't know much about the blues, but there are tons of blues harmonica clips if you look.)

PS. Also, I've only talked about the standard blues tuned harmonica before the links, but the number of people making use of alternate tunings are increasing. Today, many tunings are available off the shelf, which may have more bends, better bends, fit better for a certain genre etc. Being a traditionalist is fine, some of the greatest are, but the new tunings open up a lot of possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you could play only one major and one relative minor octave on a diatonic harmonica. That would mean it has only six holes, say.

If you mean you can play a couple of octaves major, and a couple of octaves relative minor scales, it would make more sense. But it's still a diatonic instrument, in whatever key, playing only seven out of the twelve notes used in music.

So, the answer is a resounding no. You'd be able to find enough notes to play any diatonic tune, but trying to play most minor songs would leave you searching for that sharpened leading note, not available on that harmonica. The other five notes also come into play (or out to play, if you like) often, in pieces that use *chromatic* notes (out of the key). While you may be skilled enough to bend other notes to produce those, merely blowing and sicking will leave you without them. So, no.